# Ramda: if property exists, use it, if not, check if another property exists and use it

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have several calls from different APIs. All return different data.
So, some return "position": "Frontend developer",
some "title": "Frontend developer",
some "title-position": "Frontend developer",
and some don't return any of those three

So, what I want is to use ramda to get the right property. If API return position, use position. If it returns title, use title. If it returns title-position, return it. If there is no property like any of these three, just use empty string.

How to do that using ramda?

I know of R.propOr('', 'title'), but that is only if that property exists, use it, if not, use empty string. I want to check for three different properties using ramda, instead of using switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramda has nothing built-in for this.  But it's not hard to build one yourself using some Ramda functions.

```js
const firstProp = 
  ( dflt
  , names
  , obj
  , key = find (has (__, obj), names)
  ) =>
    key ? obj[key] : dflt

console.log
  ( firstProp
    ( -1 
    , ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
    , {grault: 1, baz: 42, corg: 100, qux: 5}
    )
  )
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
const {__, find, has} = R;
</script>
```

And of course we can wrap this in `curry` if we like.

But we have to ask *why* you want to use Ramda for this.  Note that I'm an author of Ramda and a big fan; but I don't think there is a reason to use it unless it offers something I don't easily get from core Javascript.

Here that's not the case, as we could just as easily write this as

```
const firstProp = 
  ( dflt
  , names
  , obj
  , key = names.find (n => n in obj)
  ) =>
    key ? obj[key] : dflt
```